# A question about sentence order

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw a sentence of an sample answer:
It is true that **many older people believe in traditional values that** often seem incompatible with the needs of younger people

In my opinion, my sentence is better:
It is true that **the traditional values that many older people believes** often seems incompatible with the needs of younger people

Are both sentences correct? If they are, which one is better?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Hello Spider, I've closed this question as off-topic for this site because we don't do proof-reading. If you've got a question about some aspect of English sentence structure or semantics and these are an example of it, please rephrase your question to be about that. BTW, it should read, "*...that many older people **believe** often **seem** incompatible...*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are correct (if you change the "believes" to "believe" and "seems" to "seem" in the second sentence). They focus on different things though: the subject of the first is "older people" while the subject of the second is "traditional values." It really depends what you're trying to get across.